# How can I get the page source, without showing the page opened, using selenium with chromedriver and python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium with Chrome driver; How can I get the page source, without showing  the page opened? What I should specify in webdriver.ChromeOptions()?
Here the code:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("???")
bowser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)


browser = webdriver.Chrome() 
try:
    browser.get("www.google.com")
    html_content = browser.page_source
    #do stuff
    browser.quit()
except WebDriverException:
    print "Invalid URL"
```

Comment: What do you mean "new page opening"?

Comment: @NullPointer `get` is meant to open a page. Why do you want it _not_ to open a page?

Comment: @Würgspaß I just want to load the page content in a variable, like html_content = browser.page_source, and not show the page opened. Is it possible?

Comment: Is it mandatory for you to use `selenium`? You can do this with libs such as `requests`, `pycurl`...

Comment: @Andersson it's no mandatory, but using `requests` I can't get the dynamic html code, generated, for example, by javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `ChromeDriver` but some headless Webdriver like `HtmlUnitDriver`, explained [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#htmlunit-driver)

Answer (score 0):

If you are adamant to use selenium, then you can use any of the headless browsers such as htmlunit driver.
Else you can can just send a get request on the URL and get the response text.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium / Chrome has a headless option, which allows you to load webpages from code:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
browser = Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path='path_to_chromedriver')
browser.get('https://wwww.mywebsite.com')
```